# pljson does 11g installation require specific actions

Tags: oracle11g, pljson

I want to use pljson in 11g and I notice some comments in the install.sql file around 11g. Do I need to do any specific actions to enable 11g specific features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section you're asking about is lines 4 through 8 in the install.sql script:

```
/*
11g
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL = 3;
ALTER SESSION SET plsql_code_type = 'NATIVE';
*/
ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL = 2;
```

If you're using Oracle 11g then you can comment out the last `ALTER` statement and uncomment the first two `ALTER` statements. This will net you a marginal performance increase.

But there is no requirement that you do so.